# Spring data repository with empty IN clause

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring data JPA like this:

```
    public interface SampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Sample, Integer>{

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Sample s WHERE ((:ids) IS NULL OR s.id IN (:ids))")
            List<Sample> queryIn(@Param("ids") List<Integer> ids);
    }
```

But when ids is not empty, I got (1,2,3) is null which is incorrect in mysql.

If I write like this:

```
    public interface SampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Sample, Integer>{
    @Query("SELECT s FROM Sample s WHERE s.id IN (:ids)")
            List<Sample> queryIn(@Param("ids") List<Integer> ids);
    }
```

When ids is empty, I got s.id in (null)

If I must use native query to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use ISNULL function to see if :ids has a value or not

```
SELECT s FROM Sample s WHERE s.id IN (:ids)) or ISNULL(:ids) = 1
```